# prolog check uneven occurence of an element in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to make the uneven version of this prolog predicate :

```
p([ ]).
p([a, a|X]) :- p(X).
```

This returns true if the number of occurrences of "a" is even.
I don't get how to make it return true if the number is odd.
help please.

Answer (score 0):

You want the straightforward realization of the inductive definition:

Here, we use `_` as a "matches anything" placeholder instead of demanding the presence of `a` atoms:

```
% a list with 1 entry has an odd number of entries

odd_entries([_]).

% a list with 2 entries followed by a list `More` has
% an odd number of entries of `More` has an odd number of entries

odd_entries([_,_|More]) :- odd_entries(More).
```

Given a list of any length, this definition terminates eventually as the list is reduced by 2 entries on each call. The recursive call keeps the quality of odd-sizedness / even-sizedness of the list, too, so this is waht we want.

Try this with an unspecified list to generate proposals for lists with an odd number of entries:

```
?- odd_entries(L).
L = [_2494] ;
L = [_3234, _3240, _3246] ;
L = [_3234, _3240, _3986, _3992, _3998] ;
L = [_3234, _3240, _3986, _3992, _4738, _4744, _4750] ;
...
```